# ArrayList as a function's parameter, but failed to pass out?

Tags: java, arraylist

I wrote a function to process some ArrayList, and want to pass out the lists to outer caller. But I found the list was not changed after calling the function.

Here are some test code (of coz, it's a demo but illustrates my problem):

```
@Test
public void testList() {
    List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
    List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
    l1.add(11); l1.add(12); l1.add(13); l1.add(14); l1.add(15);
    l2.add(21); l2.add(22); l2.add(23); l2.add(24); l2.add(25);
    System.out.println("outer l1: " + l1);
    System.out.println("outer l2: " + l2);

    subList(l1, l2);  //call the function

    System.out.println("after l1: " + l1);
    System.out.println("after l2: " + l2);
}

protected static void subList(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) {
    l1.remove(0);  l1.remove(0);
    l2 = l2.subList(0, 4);
    System.out.println("inner l1: " + l1);
    System.out.println("inner l2: " + l2);
}
```

And the result is:

```
outer l1: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
outer l2: [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
inner l1: [13, 14, 15]             (in function, changed)
inner l2: [21, 22, 23, 24]         (in function, changed too)
after l1: [13, 14, 15]             (changed)
after l2: [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]     (unchanged?!)
```

It seems that List2 has not changed by function **subList(List l1, List l2)**,   while List1 changed.

Is the List parameter passed by CopyValue?? So, in the function, when l2's reference changed, JVM copy a new list, the original outer list is maintain old value?

How to write a **"side-effect" procedure** to modify ArrayList ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References are always passed by value in Java. So, assigning a new value to `l2` in the called method won't change the reference in the calling method.

You need the following code for it to work:

```
List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<Integer>(l2.subList(0, 4));
l2.clear();
l2.addAll(subList);
```

Comment: +1 I think the main misunderstanding from OP is the distinction between the list object itself and the references to it. While references are passed by value they still can point to the same object and you see changes through the other references. (`l1`) But pointing a reference to another object does not change the original object and its references to it. (`l2`)

Answer (score 1):

The `subList` method creates *a new* list object, and the old one will remain unchanged. You could call `clear` on the old list and use `addAll` to copy the data from the new list back into it...

Comment: Thanks.  clear, then addAll. It works. But is there any perfomance problem?

Comment: `List.subList()` does *not* create a new list object: ["Returns a view of the portion of this list"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Cf. JB Nizet's answer.

Comment: Well, it is actually a new object. It might delegate to the old list, but it is a new object and it behaves as on in terms of mutation.

Comment: @hongtium: I wouldn't expect a big performance hit, but this technique will require a few loops over the lists...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
l2 = l2.subList(0, 4);
```

This allocates `l2` to a new object, and since Java is only pass by value (not reference) you can only modify the original object in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The `subList` is a view on the data in the original list (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)).    It has the same references as the original list, but any structural changes (such as removing items) are not reflected in the original list.

You should make your changes to the original list.

Answer (score 1):

`l2.subList(0, 4);` it create a new instance of list and which you hold with l2 but instance created in main class l2 remains unchanged.

`subList(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2)` l2 refer the instance created in main class and `l2 = l2.subList(0, 4);` rewrite the l2 reference value by newly created instance. So instance created in main class is remain same.

Answer (score 0):

**-** `subList` is like a presentation of the data with in the Original List.

**-** Any changes made to the `sublist` will **not be reflected** in the Original List.

**-** Its better to use a `Copy-Constructor` to do this...

**Eg:**

`List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<Integer>(l2.subList(0, 4));`